# Hoax easy-listening record?

Tags: album, pop

Years ago I was told that someone (Eydie Gorme?) had made a record in the early '60s, possibly under a pseudonym, where she purposefully sang every song a half-tone flat, as a joke.  Has anyone else heard of that?

Comment: I can't answer that, but I'm wondering what the ploy/joke was?  She had to pay the musicians, record label and everyone else involved, and purposely record something that no one would buy because it was out of tune?  Doesn't make sense.  Sounds like one of those not-so-well-thought-out urban legends to me.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you might be thinking of the strange career of [Mrs. Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Elva_Miller).  The William Hung of her day, she was a middle-aged housewife with aspirations to opera, whose producer coaxed her into recording several hit albums of [pop-culture standards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw07CDid0JM&list=RDEMkZt6_mc4nftjS1F8gHA8LQ) in the 1960's.  The majority of her appeal was based on the modesty of her talents, and she later accused her producer of deliberately making her sound worse than she actually was.